# PDO prepared statement with placeholder not work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have some problems with execute a PDO.
No error, just nothing happens. The code looks like:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `member_accounts` ('firstname','lastname','email','password') VALUES (:fname,:lname,:e,:pw)");
                 $arr = array(
                    ':fname' => $_POST['firstname'],
                    ':lname' => $_POST['lastname'],
                    ':e' => $_POST['email'],
                    ':pw' => $_POST['password'],
                    );
                 $stmt->execute($arr);
```

Anyone see the problem? I'm to new at PDO.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove single quotes here

```
('firstname','lastname','email','password')
```

Right statement will be

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `member_accounts` (firstname,lastname,email,password) VALUES (:fname,:lname,:e,:pw)");
```

You can also use backtick(`) with column name but not single quotes.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `member_accounts` (`firstname`,`lastname`,`email`,`password`) VALUES (:fname,:lname,:e,:pw)");
```

Comment: Thanks, why did i not test it.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
        $sql="INSERT INTO `member_accounts`   
                     (firstname,lastname,email,password)  VALUES    
                      (:fname,:lname,:e,:pw)";
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
          //pdo $stmt is false if any error occur
          if($stmt)
         {

             $arr = array(
                ':fname' => $_POST['firstname'],
                ':lname' => $_POST['lastname'],
                ':e' => $_POST['email'],
                ':pw' => $_POST['password'],
                );
             $stmt->execute($arr);

         }
```